# Find all positive values for j,k,l such that j, k, l are positive integers and (j-k)|l, (k-l)|j, (l-j)|k.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

Find all possible values of $j,k,l$ such that $j, k, l$ are positive integers and $(j-k)|l, (k-l)|j, (l-j)|k$.

As I understand that using divisibility properties, it is possible to come to some complex equation with a number of unknowns. However, I think that I am missing something, as it seems that the solution should be more elegant. What properties should be used to solve the problem? Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: $1, 2, 3$ is one solution. Multiply the solution by any natural number, and you have more solutions. $1, 3, 4$ as well. I don't think any more solutions have $1$ in them.