# Assume that d,u,q are all positive integers. Also, d-u is divisible by q, u-q is divisible by d and q-d is divisible by u.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Assume that d,u,q are all positive integers. Also, d-u is divisible by q, u-q is divisible by d and q-d is divisible by u.

What is the solution for $d,u,q$?

Am I right to assume that the solution is $(1,1,1)k$ where $k$ is any positive integer, except $0$?

Comment: Well does $1|0$?

Comment: It boils down to check whether $0=x+y+z+xyz$ has integer solutions where $x,y,z$ are the quotients. However, $(1,1,2)k$ also meets the statement.

Comment: There's a [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263808) that is basically a reversal of the divisibility conditions (no answer though).